# Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-errors

I am getting a bizarre error that has crippled an application with tens of compile errors that were not there before this issue occurred. Most of the compile error's are not recognizing objects in the XAML code that were fine before this error.

The error,

> Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' because it has not
>   been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent
>   assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
>   ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

The events leading up to this are,

- 2 of us collaborating on GitHub
- The other collaborator downloaded Windows Office reference for Excel
- Office.Interop.Excel reference seems to all be there on my end
- When updating to last commit, runs fine on my machine until I re-build solution
- Runs fine on collaborator's machine.
- I have never used SharePoint on my machine.

I have never come across something like this. From what I can see the required references are there. I am lost as to what I need to do to get this to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was that the other collaborator had installed `Office Developer Tools` and after I downloaded them as well, all the compile errors were fixed. It seems that not all the references were there.

I hope this helps someone in the future.